# Multiple dimensions array How could I sum the values ​of the columns?

Tags: javascript

I am completely stuck, I am trying to sum the columns of the array, but I had try during 6 hours and I couldn't find the way to do it :(

I found the way to sum the rows but not the columns and I don´t know what I am doing wrong. It is so frustranting. I will apreciate any light to find the way to do it.

I am not using the index 0. All the values start to be stored from index (1x1) row1 x column1 letting the latest rows and columns empty to print the sum of the rows and the sum of the columns

```js
let row, qtyRow, qtyColumn, i, sumaRow, numberRow, sumaColumn, column

qtyRow = parseInt(prompt(`How many rows in the array?`))
qtyRow = qtyRow + 2
var mainTab = [qtyRow]

qtyColumn = parseInt(prompt(`How many columns in the array?`))
qtyColumn = qtyColumn + 2

/* Asignación de nuevo Array al Array principal. Poniendo las columnas a las filas */
for (i = 0; i < qtyRow; i++) {
  mainTab[i] = new Array(qtyColumn)
  console.log(mainTab)
}

/* Entry of numbers for rows and columns and the last column it left empty */
let counterRow = 1
for (row = 1; row < qtyRow - 1; row++) {
  for (column = 1; column < qtyColumn - 1; column++) {
    dataTable = parseInt(prompt(`Value of row ${(counterRow)} column ${(column)}?`))
    mainTab[row][column] = dataTable
  }
  counterRow++
}

/* printing numbers and adding rows*/
counterRow = 1
for (row = 1; row < qtyRow; row++) {
  document.write(`<br><b>Row ${counterRow} - </b>`)

  sumaRow = 0
  for (column = 1; column < qtyColumn; column++) {
    if (column === qtyColumn - 1) {
      document.write(" " + `<b>${sumaRow}</b>`)
    } else {
      document.write(mainTab[row][column] + " | ")
      sumaRow = sumaRow + mainTab[row][column]
    }
  }
  counterRow++
}
```

Comment: You do exactly the same thing you're doing to create `sumaRow`, just with the `for (column =` loop on the outside and the `for (row =` loop on the inside.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder I did it, but doesn´t work. I will do again (I deleted it) and paste it here

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have two arrays of different length and you want to produce a third array where each element will be the sum of the elements of the other arrays

```
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const arr2 = [1, 2, 3];
// get the length
const [len1, len2] = [arr1.length, arr2.length];
// find the smallest and the largest array
const [small, large] = (len1>len2)?[arr2, arr1]:[arr1, arr2];
const arr3 = [];
let i;
// fill the output array until we reach the length of the smallest one
for(i = 0; i<small.length; ++i) arr3.push(small[i] + large[i]);
// fill the rest
for(; i<large.length; ++i) arr3.push(large[i]);
```

Comment: tkanks. @Alexandre Senges 

My goal it´s do the array dynamic and be able type the number of rows and columns, afterwards fill the array and  once it have done,  use the latest rows and columns to have the total of each row and each column

Answer (score 0):

I calculate the row and col sums with a double reduce function

```js
let row, qtyRow, qtyColumn, i, sumaRow, numberRow, sumaColumn, column

qtyRow = parseInt(prompt(`How many rows in the array?`))
var mainTab = [qtyRow]

qtyColumn = parseInt(prompt(`How many columns in the array?`))
qtyColumn = qtyColumn

/* Asignación de nuevo Array al Array principal. Poniendo las columnas a las filas */
for (i = 0; i < qtyRow; i++) {
  mainTab[i] = new Array(qtyColumn)
}


/* Entry of numbers for rows and columns and the last column it left empty */
let counterRow = 1
for (row = 0; row < qtyRow; row++) {
  for (column = 0; column < qtyColumn; column++) {
    dataTable = parseInt(prompt(`Value of row ${counterRow + 1} column ${column + 1}?`))
    mainTab[row][column] = dataTable
  }
  counterRow++
}


// Calculating the sums of rows and cols

let rowsums = [], colsums = [];
mainTab.reduce((colsums, row, indexRow, source) => {
  row.reduce((rowsums, col, indexCol, source2) => {
    rowsums[indexRow] = (rowsums[indexRow] || 0) + col
    colsums[indexCol] = (colsums[indexCol] || 0) + col
    return rowsums
  }, rowsums)
  return colsums
}, colsums)

// Output table and sums as <table>
document.write('<table border="1">');

mainTab.forEach((row, index) => {
  
  document.write(`<tr><th>Row ${index + 1}:</th>`);
  row.forEach((col, index2) => {
    document.write(`<td>${col}</td>`)
    // console.log(row, index, col, index2)
  })
  document.write(`<th>${rowsums[index]}</th></tr>`)
})

document.write(`<tr><th>Sum:</th>`);
colsums.forEach((col, index2) => {
  document.write(`<th>${col}</th>`)
  // console.log(row, index, col, index2)
})
document.write('<th>' + colsums.reduce((accu, col) => accu + col, 0) + "</th>")

document.write('</table>');
```

Comment: thank you very much @yunzen I have to study your code to understand it. I am beginner in JS and I did not know forEach,  but it´s perfect, after your suggestion it's time to read about it, thanks again

Comment: If you think my (or anyone's) answer is correct, please accept it by using the gray tick mark left to the answer

Comment: I did, but unfortunately I can´t cause my reputation is less than 15